# How to output regression summary(e.g p-value and coeff) into a rasterbrick?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am using R to perform my regression. I was successfully extract the r-squared, residual standard error into a rasterbrick. Then I need to run another code to get the p-value(F stat). How could I combine fun1 and fun2 so that I can produce a rasterbrick that contains those informations in one go?

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)

#1 create test data
 r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
 set.seed(0)
 s <- stack(lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3) )))
 time <- 1:nlayers(s)
 s[1:5] <- NA

#2 Run function1 to obtain r-squared and residual standard error
 fun1 <- function(x) {
 if (all(is.na(x))) {
 return(cbind(NA,NA))
 }
 m = lm(x~time)
 s  <- summary(m)
 r2 <- s$r.squared
 resid.s.e <- s$sigma
 cbind(r2, resid.s.e)
 }

#3 Run function to obtaion p-value(from F stat)
 fun2 <- function(x) {
 if (all(is.na(x))) {
 return(cbind(NA,NA))
 }
 m = lm(x~time)
 s  <- summary(m)
 r2 <- s$r.squared
 pf<- pf(s$fstatistic[1], s$fstatistic[2], s$fstatistic[3],lower.tail = FALSE) 
 cbind(r2, pf)
 }

#Apply both functions with rasterstack and plot
 r <- calc(s, fun)
 plot(r)

 r2 <- calc(s, fun2)
 plot(r2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your text says p-value and your title says coefficients. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks @Roman Lustrik. Edited my title and post. I was in a rush and got mixed up. Apologies.

Comment: Why not keep 1 function that returns both `resid.s.e` and `pf`, then choose variables to pass on to `calc`? Recalculating same `lm` again seems redundant.

Comment: Yes you are right @zx8754. I just could not figure it out how to do it before. I think I found the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

Adding few more columns in cbind() will allow me to add more layers in the output rasterstack.

```
library(raster)

#1 create test data
  r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
  set.seed(0)
  s <- stack(lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3) )))
  time <- 1:nlayers(s)
  s[1:5] <- NA

#2 Run function1 to obtain r-squared, residual standard error and p-value(F stat)
  fun <- function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x))) {
  return(cbind(NA,NA,NA))
  }
  m = lm(x~time)
  s  <- summary(m)
  r2 <- s$r.squared
  resid.s.e <- s$sigma
  pf<- pf(s$fstatistic[1], s$fstatistic[2], s$fstatistic[3],lower.tail = FALSE) 
  cbind(r2, resid.s.e, pf)
  }

  r <- calc(s, fun)
  r
   class       : RasterBrick 
   dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
   resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
   extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
   data source : in memory
   names       :      layer.1,      layer.2,      layer.3 
   min values  : 1.300285e-01, 1.457297e+00, 5.199987e-07 
   max values  :    0.9271788,    5.0219805,    0.2495312
```